# VS 2010 is broken

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Today i was working on a project when a broken HDD froze my computer. I took out the offending hardware and restarted. After that I discovered that the file i was working on was corrupted, neither VS or notepad could make sense of it. Annoying but meh, it would take me 10 mins to rewrite i figured.

Then a few hours later I went out, saved my work and closed VS. When i came back VS threw me an error when loading up, something about an exception and that i should check the log file(which I did, I'll add the error below). And again there was corruption, this time 2 files. This is really lame.

The error is as follows:

> System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError() at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost) at System.Windows.Input.Cursor.LoadFromStream(Stream cursorStream) at System.Windows.Input.Cursor..ctor(Stream cursorStream) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.LeftSelectionMargin.get_RightArrowCursor() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.LeftSelectionMarginProvider.CreateMargin(IWpfTextViewHost textViewHost, IWpfTextViewMargin containerMargin) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.ContainerMargin.b__2(IWpfTextViewMarginProvider mp) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InstantiateExtension[TExtension,TMetadata,TExtensionInstance](Object errorSource, Lazy`2 provider, Func`2 getter)"

It makes no sense to me.. Anybody know how to fix things?